How to have multiple IFERROR statements in one cell in Excel?
I am trying to write a formula to search through three keywords. The words are written in a lab report, and the name of one chemical compound may be different depending on which laboratory writes the report.
I have tried the two following formulas but have not had any luck. The return response reads NA when I have an exact match in the table array.

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("2-Butanone (MEK)"&"Methyl Ethyl Ketone"&"2-butanone",$AG5:$AI343,1,FALSE),"NA")
=IFERROR(OR(VLOOKUP("2-Butanone (MEK)",AG5:AI343,1,FALSE),VLOOKUP("Methyl Ethyl Ketone",$AG5:$AI343,1,FALSE),VLOOKUP("2-butanone",$AG5:$AI343,1,FALSE)),"NA")



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Try this variant:
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("2-Butanone (MEK)",AG5:AI343,1,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP("Methyl Ethyl Ketone",$AG5:$AI343,1,FALSE),IFERROR(VLOOKUP("2-butanone",$AG5:$AI343,1,FALSE),"NA")))

Another possible formula:
=LET(res,CONCAT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP({"2-Butanone (MEK)","Methyl Ethyl Ketone","2-butanone"},AG5:AI343,1,FALSE),"")),IF(res="","NA",res))


Try:
=LET(
    _x, XLOOKUP(
        {
            "2-Butanone (MEK)";
            "Methyl Ethyl Ketone";
            "2-butanone"
        },
        $AG$4:$AG$338,
        $AG$4:$AG$338,
        ""
    ),
    FILTER(_x, _x <> "")
)

Still a long but avoids IFERROR(). Semicolons transpose XLOOKUP() results.
